# Fixed header in DataGrid control

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am unable to find the solution after much searching in too many sites.
Could you please help me how to fix the datagrid header while scrolling vertically?

I applied all the code changes which were given in different sites with no success.

```
<div class="radgrd1 radgrd123"> <div id="divTransfers" runat="server"> <asp:DataGrid ID="dgPTransfers" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" CellSpacing="0" border="0" Style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: auto; empty-cells: show;" CssClass="MasterTable_Grid"> <HeaderStyle CssClass="Grid_Header" /> <ItemStyle CssClass="GridRow_Grid" /> <Columns></Columns></div></div>
```

I applied `position: relative` CSS for the 2nd column header, but it's working only for IE, not for Chrome or Mozilla browsers.

Comment: Can we see a bit more code? Ideally if you can also accompany this with a JS Fiddle or similar, so the problem is reproduced for readers, that is also helpful.

Comment: What DataGrid are you using? Is this a jQuery plugin or .net library?

Comment: <div class="radgrd1 radgrd123">
                    <div id="divTransfers" runat="server">
                        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgPTransfers" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
                            CellSpacing="0" border="0" Style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: auto;
                            empty-cells: show;" CssClass="MasterTable_Grid">
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="Grid_Header" />
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="GridRow_Grid" />
                            <Columns></Columns></div></div>

Comment: Above is the snippet of the code. Here I used position:relative for the 2nd column header its working in only IE browser. Header staying fixed. But same change is not working other browsers .

Comment: That's a start, would you edit those items into the question please? Code formatting tools are available there.

Comment: No, Just need to display as static data in datagrid control. Only when I scroll vertically header is also scrolling along with records.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10068/Fixed-header-in-ASP-NET-DataGrid.  I used this code also, but it's working only in IE browser.

Comment: I've added your HTML to your question, though it could do with some formatting - feel free to edit further.